# Disabling annoying VMware Player tool tip “To release input, press Ctrl+Alt”

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player

[Same as [Hide annoying VMware hint "To release input, press Ctrl+Alt"](https://superuser.com/questions/384205/hide-annoying-vmware-hint-to-release-input-press-ctrlalt) but for VMware Player, because that answer was for VMware Workstation]

When starting the VMWare Player, at the top it always displays this tooltip:

To release input, press Ctrl+Alt

This tooltip obscures a part of the VM (often the menu of a program I'm using) and it's annoying as hell.

Need to disable it, but the solution for VMware Workstation doesn't work for VMware Player. I.e., I didn't find the "Grab keyboard and mouse input on mouse click" Preferences in VMware Player.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide annoying VMware hint "To release input, press Ctrl+Alt"](https://superuser.com/questions/384205/hide-annoying-vmware-hint-to-release-input-press-ctrlalt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I write down my Answer here, just because i cannot comment under [Hide annoying VMware hint “To release input, press Ctrl+Alt”](https://superuser.com/a/867226/253367)*

My Solution is same as the one [Maxime Poulin](https://superuser.com/a/867226/253367) mentioned in the link above. But we need to modify other file: `vmclientcore.dll` within the VMPlayer Version 7.1.0 (Windows X64)

1. backup your old `vmclientcore.dll`
2. open the `vmclientcore.dll` with whatever a hex-editor
3. replace `@&!*@*@(msg.vmui.fullScreen.ungrab.tooltip)To release input, press %s` with dots (`00` <del>or `2E`</del>).
   **Edit: don't replace with `2E`, it will cause an error**
4. *in the same file you could find other tooltips in the same format begin with* `@&!*@*@(msg.`
5. Save the file and start VMPlayer again. This should work.

Comment: This also works with VMPlayer 11. The first message is "to direct input..." The second is "to return to your computer press..". Amazing we need to resort to hexedit to disable these annoying popups.

Comment: Works for VMware Workstation 12 Player. Thanks.

Comment: In VMware Workstation Player 15 the string is `@&!*@*@(msg.player.vmWindow.statusRelease)To return to your computer, press %s.`

Answer (score 1):

I confirm this also works with VMware Workstation Player 16.

The two strings are  *@&!*@*@(msg.player.vmWindow.statusGrabVM)To direct input to this virtual machine, press Ctrl+G*
and
*@&!*@*@(msg.player.vmWindow.statusRelease)To return to your computer, press %s..*